# Show Countable Additivity is Equivalent to Continuity for Monotone Sequences?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Show that the property of countable additivity of a probability measure is equivalent to its property of continuity for monotone sequences of sets. That is, a probability measure satisfies countable additivity **iff** it is continuous for monotone sequences of sets.

*Countable Additivity*:

$$\mu\big{(}\bigcup_{t \in T}A_t\big{)} = \sum_{t \in T}\mu\big{(}A_t\big{)}$$

*Monotonicity*:

If $A,B \in F$ such that $A \subset B$, then $P(A) \leq P(B)$

**Question:**

How do I properly show:

If $A_1, A_2, \cdots, \in F$ and ${A_j} \uparrow A$ then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{P}\{A_n\} = \text{P}\{A\}$$
implies countable additivity?

Comment: Rewrite the union of the $A_i$ as a disjoint union.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri If $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n \in F$ are disjoint, then:
$\text{P}\big{\{}\bigcup_{t \in T}A_t\big{\}} = \sum_{t \in T}\text{P}\big{\{}A_t\big{\}}$ but doesn't that simply state the disjoint set implies the limit? Not the other way around?

Comment: Do not assume that the $A_i$ are disjoint, but *re*write their union as the union of disjoint sets. For instance, we have $A_1\cup A_2 = A_1 \cup \big(A_2\setminus A_1\big)$, but the second expression is a disjoint union.